# NumPy replace values in matrix with np array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have numpy array like:

```
x = np.array([
    ...
    [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    ...
])
```

with shape `(4800, 4, 4)`.

So i need to replace every `0` with `[1, 1, 2]` and every `1` with `[5, 5, 9]`

Result should be like this:

```
[[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]],
[[1, 1, 2], [5, 5, 9], [5, 5, 9], [1, 1, 2]],
[[1, 1, 2], [5, 5, 9], [5, 5, 9], [1, 1, 2]],
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2]]]
```

**How do I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that you have 0 and 1, define a mapper array and index it:

```
                  #    0          1
mapper = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [5, 5, 9]])

out = mapper[a]
```

output:

```
array([[[[1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2]],

        [[1, 1, 2],
         [5, 5, 9],
         [5, 5, 9],
         [1, 1, 2]],

        [[1, 1, 2],
         [5, 5, 9],
         [5, 5, 9],
         [1, 1, 2]],

        [[1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2],
         [1, 1, 2]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array and assign the values according to the value in the old one.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([
    [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 1, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
])

x_new = np.zeros((*(x.shape), 3))
x_new[x==0] = [1, 1, 2]
x_new[x==1] = [5, 5, 9]

print(x_new)
```

This results in the following output:

```
[[[[1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]]

  [[1. 1. 2.]
   [5. 5. 9.]
   [5. 5. 9.]
   [1. 1. 2.]]

  [[1. 1. 2.]
   [5. 5. 9.]
   [5. 5. 9.]
   [1. 1. 2.]]

  [[1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]]]]
```